# 'C:\' in CMD, the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java, windows, path, cmd, javac

Recently started trying to learn java and the first thing I needed to do was to make a PATH variable. My path variable looks like this.

```
C:\Users\Collin>echo %path%
'C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin';C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;
'C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin';C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;
```

So, I attempt to use javac to see if path did work. Javac did not work, showing the error of not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
I then tried just using path and I got this:

```
C:\Users\Collin>%path%
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I then tried to just use basic explorer paths such as 'C:\' and tried another drive as 'G:\'. I've tried almost every variation of quotations and formatting but nothing seems to work.

```
C:\Users\Collin>C:\
'C:\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Collin>'C:\'
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\Collin>"C:\"
'"C:\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Collin>'G:\'
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit as my OS. Will I have to just format my HDD? This seems to be a problem with the registry, and as such I'm thinking that I will have to format and reinstall. But, maybe there is something I didn't catch that you guys can? Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if you tell me I have to format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use " instead of ' to escape paths with spaces

Comment: Remove ' from path.  Use set path=C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;

Comment: Attempted with both methods. Returning different errors.


C:\Users\Collin>%path%
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


C:\Users\Collin>path
PATH=C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32

Comment: A drive's root directory is not an executable file, nor is the Windows path, so those error messages are as expected.  Also, do not use quote marks in the path environment variable.

Answer (score 7):

1. press Windows-key and Pause-key together <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Pause</kbd>
2. select "Advanced system settings"
3. in "System Properties" press the button "Environment Variables"
4. select "Path" in the upper part and press "Edit...":
   [image]
5. append `;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin` to the path:
   [image]
6. <kbd>OK</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what the problem is. It looks like you installed java to C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40 and wants to use javac to compile a program.

- Start cmd
- set path=C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;%path%
- Create a Java class (HellowWorld.java)
- Compile using javac  HelloWorld.java
- Run it using java HelloWorld

Comment: I set the path exactly as you said and I created the HelloWorld.java class as well. The problem is that javac is not being recognized as a command because something is going wrong in my path variable and when I even attempt to use the most basic of paths in command prompt, it will return an error. Such as above when I simply type 'C:\' in command prompt, it doesn't recgonize 'C:\' or any variation ("C:\" C:\ etc.) of it as a path. It returns these errors:

Comment: C:\Users\Collin>"C:\"
'"C:\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Collin>'C:\'
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\Collin>C:\
'C:\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> C:\program files\

put

> C:\progra~1\

Comment: -1.  There's no good reason to use short path names in the PATH.